# How do I use Source Control with SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: tfs, ssms

How do I use Source Control with SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: What version of SSMS, and what version of TFS? Also what do you mean by "this will be self-answered". If that's the case, why ask the question on SO?

Comment: Because there was no existing answer for this question.

Comment: Azure Data Studio has Database projects which can be used with version control since it is just text files of the definitions in a folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer20132015M), which enables integrated use of Team Foundation Version Control with products that do not support Team Explorer integration.

Answer (score 5):

My solution is only version history. I have a scheduled powershell script that generates the definitions of specified objects (stored procs, functions, tables, and views). It then uses git to update a GitLab repository. Git will only update if there are changes in the file contents so it is okay to generate all of the scripts each time.

```
function SQL-Script-Database
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Script all database objects for the given database.

    .DESCRIPTION
    This  function scripts all database objects  (i.e.: tables,  views, stored
    procedures,  and user defined functions) for the specified database on the
    the given server. It creates a subdirectory per object type under 
    the path specified.

    .PARAMETER savePath
    The root path where to save object definitions.

    .PARAMETER database
    The database to script (default = $global:DatabaseName)

    .PARAMETER DatabaseServer 
    The database server to be used (default: $global:DatabaseServer).

    #>

    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $savePath,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string] $database = $global:DatabaseName,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string] $DatabaseServer = $global:DatabaseServer
    )

    try
    {
        if (!$DatabaseServer)
            { throw "`$DatabaseServer or `$InstanceName variable is not properly initialized" }

        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null

        $s = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($DatabaseServer)
        $db = $s.databases[$database]

        $objects = $db.Tables
        $objects += $db.Views
        $objects += $db.StoredProcedures
        $objects += $db.UserDefinedFunctions

        $scripter = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter') ($s)

        $scripter.Options.AnsiFile = $true
        $scripter.Options.IncludeHeaders = $false
        $scripter.Options.ScriptOwner = $false
        $scripter.Options.AppendToFile = $false
        $scripter.Options.AllowSystemobjects = $false
        $scripter.Options.ScriptDrops = $false
        $scripter.Options.WithDependencies = $false
        $scripter.Options.SchemaQualify = $false
        $scripter.Options.SchemaQualifyForeignKeysReferences = $false
        $scripter.Options.ScriptBatchTerminator = $false

        $scripter.Options.Indexes = $true
        $scripter.Options.ClusteredIndexes = $true
        $scripter.Options.NonClusteredIndexes = $true
        $scripter.Options.NoCollation = $true

        $scripter.Options.DriAll = $true
        $scripter.Options.DriIncludeSystemNames = $false

        $scripter.Options.ToFileOnly = $true
        $scripter.Options.Permissions = $true

        foreach ($o in $objects | where {!($_.IsSystemObject)}) 
        {
            $typeFolder=$o.GetType().Name 

            if (!(Test-Path -Path "$savepath\$typeFolder")) 
                { New-Item -Type Directory -name "$typeFolder"-path "$savePath" | Out-Null }

            $file = $o -replace "\[|\]"
            $file = $file.Replace("dbo.", "")

            $scripter.Options.FileName = "$savePath\$typeFolder\$file.sql"
            $scripter.Script($o)
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        Write-Error "`t`t$($MyInvocation.InvocationName): $_"
    }
}

# repeat line for each database/server to be pushed to version control 
SQL-Script-Database C:\Users\UserName\DbObjDef\FolderName DatabaseName ServerName

cd C:\Users\UserName\DbObjDef
git add .
git commit -m "nightly diff" 
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL database versioning directly from SSMS can be accomplished using various 3rd party add-ins. For example ApexSQL Source Control has seamless SSMS integration and it can be used not just with TFS, but the following SC systems are supported out of the box: Git, Subversion, Mercurial, Perforce. Team Foundation Server support includes an online version, Visual Studio Team Services.

As explained in [this article](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-use-source-control-with-sql-server-management-studio-ssms/), the ApexSQL Source Control add-in introduces, amongst other things, an IDE called the Action center tab allows you to maintain your source control repository without necessarily having to first script out database objects. Usually the Action center tab will automatically be opened as soon as you finish linking a database into a source control repository but you can still manually open it through keyboard combination keys Ctrl + Alt + A or by right clicking the source control-linked database and navigating to the Action center option.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling source control integration in SSMS To enable TFS integration in SSMS, follow these steps:

1) Close SSMS if it is running.

2) Install Visual Studio 2015 on your SSMS machine. If you don’t already have Visual Studio, Community Edition will work fine. This is a large download but you can save some space by unselecting all languages during the Visual Studio install if your only purpose is to enable Source Control in SSMS.

3) Edit the ssms.pkgundef file found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.pkgundef.

At the top of this file there are a series of packages grouped together related to TFS Source Control features. These packages must be removed from the pkgundef file. This can be done by either deleting the section or commenting out each line using ‘//’. Here is an example of what the section should look like if commented out:// TFS SCC Configuration entries. The TFS entries block Team Explorer from loading.

```
// Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Lab
//[$RootKey$\Packages\{17c5d08a-602c-4dfb-82b5-8e0f7f50c9d7}]
// GitHub Package
//[$RootKey$\Packages\{c3d3dc68-c977-411f-b3e8-03b0dccf7dfc}]
// Team Foundation Server Provider Package
//[$RootKey$\Packages\{5BF14E63-E267-4787-B20B-B814FD043B38}]
// Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPackage
//[$RootKey$\Packages\{6238f138-0c0c-49ec-b24b-215ee59d84f0}]
// Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Build.BuildPackage
//[$RootKey$\Packages\{739f34b3-9ba6-4356-9178-ac3ea81bdf47}]
// Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking
//[$RootKey$\Packages\{ca39e596-31ed-4b34-aa36-5f0240457a7e}]
// Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation
//[$RootKey$\Packages\{b80b010d-188c-4b19-b483-6c20d52071ae}]
// Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.SccProviderPackage
//[$RootKey$\Packages\{7fe30a77-37f9-4cf2-83dd-96b207028e1b}]
// Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.SccPcwPluginPackage
//[$RootKey$\Packages\{1b4f495a-280a-3ba4-8db0-9c9b735e98ce}]
// Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.HatPackage
//[$RootKey$\Packages\{4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}]
// Visual SourceSafe Provider Package
//[$RootKey$\Packages\{AA8EB8CD-7A51-11D0-92C3-00A0C9138C45}]
// Visual SourceSafe Provider Stub Package
  [$RootKey$\Packages\{53544C4D-B03D-4209-A7D0-D9DD13A4019B}]
// Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Initialization.InitializationPackage
  [$RootKey$\Packages\{75DF55D4-EC28-47FC-88AC-BE56203C9012}]
// Team Foundation Server Provider Stub Package
  [$RootKey$\Packages\{D79B7E0A-F994-4D4D-8FAE-CAE147279E21}]
// Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.SccDisplayInformationPackage
  [$RootKey$\Packages\{D7BB9305-5804-4F92-9CFE-119F4CB0563B}]
// Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Lab.LabPcwPluginPackage
   [$RootKey$\Packages\{e0910062-da1f-411c-b152-a3fc6392ee1f}]
   [$RootKey$\ToolsOptionsPages\Source Control]
   [$RootKey$\AutoLoadPackages\{11b8e6d7-c08b-4385-b321-321078cdd1f8}]
// TFS SCC Configuration entries.
```

Once completed, start SSMS and the “Team” menu should be visible in the SSMS menu bar. This menu and related features are the standard Visual Studio functionality. This enables connections to TFS servers or Git servers.

Comment: Unfortuneatly this solution is not relevant to SQL Server Management Studio 18 (which seems to be based on VS2017) 

Answer (score -1):

It depends on which version of SSMS you are using.

If you are using a version which uses the Visual Studio shell, then it is already integrated into SSMS and all you need to do is enable it.  [This](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/11/21/source-control-in-sql-server-management-studio-ssms/) blog post from the SQL Server Team Explains how.

If you are using a prior version, then you must download and install a provider. [This](http://www.techtree.co.uk/sql-server/management-studio-ssms/use-team-foundation-server-tfs-as-your-source-control-in-ssms/) gives full details.

Comment: This is no longer the case with SSMS 18

Comment: @RowlandShaw, Thank you, I am going to try that out.